# Why is nth-of-type doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this HTML structure in my app:

```
<div className="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p className="checkout-txt">Total</p>
</div>
<div className="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p className="checkout-txt"> SHIPPING</p>
</div>
<div className="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p className="checkout-txt">VAT (INCLUDED)</p>
</div>
<div className="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p className="checkout-txt">GRAND TOTAL</p>
</div>
```

I simply want the third item will take a 24px margin, and the last item will take a 32px margin, so I did that:

```
.checkout-txt-row {
    display: flex

    &:nth-of-type(3){
        margin-bottom: 24px;
    }

    &:last-of-type {
        margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    .checkout-txt {
        opacity: 0.5;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.
The `nth-of-type` effect on the 2nd item and last-of-type don't work at all.
Why this is not working and how can I fix this?

(BTW, before that I did the exact same thing without the `checkout-txt-row` wrapper, only `nth-of-type` on `checkout-txt` and it worked great)

**EDIT**
I didn't mention this before, but I'm using react so `className` is not the problem

Comment: Are you using React or some other library/framework that requires the use of `className` over the standard `class`?

Comment: It would also be nice to show the processed HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sorry for not mention it, I'm using react..I'll add soon the processed HTML and CSS.

Comment: Are there any other `<div>` siblings? Because the term `type` in `nth-of-type` and `last-of-type` means tag type. So only if the last `div` in the container has a class `checkout-txt-row` it will match your selector, otherwise there will be no match for that selector.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `className` to `class` and CSS will work :)

Answer (score 1):

"class" not "className"

```
<div class="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p class="checkout-txt">Total</p>
</div>
<div class="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p class="checkout-txt"> SHIPPING</p>
</div>
<div class="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p class="checkout-txt">VAT (INCLUDED)</p>
</div>
<div class="checkout-txt-row ">
    <p class="checkout-txt">GRAND TOTAL</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Asking about oddities like `className`, when you have sufficient rep to comment, is a good idea.